# xcode project open without .xcodeproj file

Tags: xcode, project

how to Open an Xcode Project from Without `.xcodeproj` File .
I have an Xcode project but I am missing my main file (`.xcodeproj`) then how to start this project on Xcode framework.

Comment: Create a new project and add the files.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution/workaround. In case you recieve a project with missing `.xcodeproj` file, please create a new project and add all the files (.swift, .storyboard, etc.)and then compile. It will work.

Comment: So your solution to the question "How to I get a missing project" is "Make a new one"? That's like me asking "How can I find my lost car?" and you reply is "Buy a new one". If the project needs special build settings or must compile files in specific orders or build libraries out of subtargets, this approach will fail. It's poor coincident that it worked for your case.

Comment: So, tell me what to do then? Do you have any solution?

Comment: The solution is download the source together with the project file and let the person offering the download know that he forgotten to include the project file. An Xcode project without the actual Xcode prociect files is no Xcode project, it's just a bunch of source code files. Of course you can add source code files to your own Xcode project but  then you are creating a new Xcode project out of source code files. Then you have not downloaded an Xcode project, you just have downloaded source codes files and created your own Xcode project.

Comment: No need to be pedantic. Many projects just don't have a lot of extra settings in the project file. These will work fine if you just start a new project and put the source in there.

Answer (score -6):

The `.xcodeproj` file **is** the project. If you don't have this file, you don't have the project. The rest of the files are just files that belong to that project but how they belong there and what roles they play there is only known to the project itself and that is the `.xcodeproj` file (which actually is no file, it's a bundle, a directory but in the UI it's displayed as if it was a single file).

Comment: This answer does not provide solution to the question asked. I am facing same issue. I have downloaded a projected from internet, which has all the files and assets but the .xcodeproj' file is missing. How to fix that?

Comment: @Tejas You can't fix that. How do you want to fix a missing file? It's like saying "I decompress a ZIP archive and the file I'm looking for is not there, how do I fix that?" If the file is not in the archive, it's not in the archive. You cannot magically make a non-existing file appear. And that is also what my answer says and that is the only correct answer you will ever get.

Comment: Agreed @Mecki . I cannot magically make a file appear. but My question was if somehow you get a project / file with missing .xcodeproj then what to do. Anyways, I found the solution. Will post my answer below.